# Retrieving values from dynamically created RadioButtonList

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code-behind (c#) file declares RadioButtonLists dynamically for any given number of questions in my database using a while() loop:

I add items to each tmpRBL in a for loop.

I register each RadioButtonList to a child panel which I create at the beginning of each iteration of the while() loop.

I then add each panel to the parent panel.

```
while(reader.Read()
{ 
    ...

    RadioButtonList tmpRBL = new RadioButtonList();
    temp = "RadioButtonList" + count.ToString();
    tmpRBL.ID = temp;
    tmpRBL.RepeatDirection = System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeatDirection.Vertical;
    tmpRBL.TextAlign = System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextAlign.Left;

    ...

    for (int i = 1; i <= numAnswers; i++)
    {
        tmpItem = new ListItem("", i.ToString());
        tmpRBL.Items.Add(tmpItem);
    }

    ...

    p.Controls.Add(tmpRBL);

    ...

    questionPanel.Controls.Add(p);

}
```

How can I retrieve the selectedIndexes of these dynamically created RadioButtonLists? I've spent the better part of the day trying various fixes from other similar questions online, but have had no luck.

If I use 'Inspect Element' in Chrome, I am able to see the RadioButtonLists in their desired locations ostensibly with the ID I have assigned (RadioButtonList1, RadioButtonList2, etc), but I everything I try ends up with a null object.

I'm relatively new to C# and this is my first time dealing with dynamic controls, so big thanks in advance for any help offered.

Comment: Please give some more details, like in which page event you are creating those `RadioButton` objects. Basically, You should be able to get those controls by using `FindControl()` method (more info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw.aspx and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157788/how-can-i-use-findcontrol-method-in-asp-net).

Comment: I create all the RadioButtonLists in a function called by Page_Load since the number of RBL's is determined by the contents of my database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, if you create a control dynamically, you will need to reload those controls (***with same id***) in every post back of the page.

Otherwise, they will become null, and you won't be able to access them.

Here is a sample. It loads `RadioButtonList` control dynamically and displays the selected value back when a button is clicked.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder1"/>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Submit" />
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1"/>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoadControls();
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var radioButtonList = PlaceHolder1.FindControl("1") as RadioButtonList;
    Label1.Text = radioButtonList.SelectedValue;
}

private void LoadControls()
{
    var tmpRBL = new RadioButtonList();
    tmpRBL.ID = "1";

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        var tmpItem = new ListItem(i.ToString(), i.ToString());
        tmpRBL.Items.Add(tmpItem);
    }

    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tmpRBL);
}
```

Comment: What are the logistics of doing this if loading the controls is dependent on data from a database? Also, the end goal for this page is for users to answer a series of questions and then click submit, at which point I should grab all the selectedIndex values from all the created RBLs and move to a new page; do I need to worry about reloading controls still? Thanks for your time.

Comment: In order to ***grab all the selectedIndex values***, you need to reload those controls back with ***same ID*** on post back.

Comment: Sounds good, thanks for the quick update. I'll comment again when I've attempted to implement all this.

Answer (score 0):

Thank's a lot. In the same way, I, finnaly managed to put other controls under control :-). Here is code-behind in vb.net.

Me now very lucky :-)

Creating & Retrieving values from dynamically created RadioButtonList & TextBox

```
Private Property RadioButtonList As RadioButtonList
    Private Property TextBoxList As TextBox


    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        LoadControls()

    End Sub           



    Protected Sub Button111_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim majstor_rbl(3) As String
        Dim majstor_txt(3) As String

        For i As Integer = 1 To 3
            RadioButtonList = TryCast(PlaceHolder1.FindControl(i & "rbl"), RadioButtonList)
            majstor_rbl(i) = RadioButtonList.SelectedValue
            TextBoxList = TryCast(PlaceHolder1.FindControl(i & "txt"), TextBox)
            majstor_txt(i) = TextBoxList.Text
        Next

        txt_podatak4.Text = majstor_rbl(1) & " - " & majstor_txt(1)
        txt_podatak5.Text = majstor_rbl(2) & " - " & majstor_txt(2)
        txt_podatak6.Text = majstor_rbl(3) & " - " & majstor_txt(3)
    End Sub

    Private Sub LoadControls()
        For j As Integer = 1 To 3

            Dim tmpRBL As Object = New RadioButtonList
            Dim tmpTXT As Object = New TextBox

            tmpRBL.ID = j & "rbl"
            tmpTXT.ID = j & "txt"



            For i As Integer = 1 To 3
                Dim tmpItem As Object = New ListItem("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;", i.ToString())
                tmpRBL.Items.Add(tmpItem)
            Next


            tmpRBL.RepeatLayout = RepeatLayout.Flow
            tmpRBL.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal


            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tmpTXT)
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tmpRBL)
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(New LiteralControl("</br>"))
        Next

    End Sub
```

.aspx

```
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder1"/>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button3" OnClick="Button111_Click" Text="Submit" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_podatak4" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_podatak5" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txt_podatak6" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
```