# Find Dynamically Created Gridviews that is inside a masterpage and inside a collapsible panels

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This has definitely been a 1 step forward 43 steps back.  Started by creating by first gridview user control.  But anyway.  What I have is dynamically created gridviews. The entire page is built on masterpage and each gridview resides inside its own dynamically created collapsible panel.

Now in I need to loop through each gridview's rows.  Problem is I cannot find them in the code behind.  I have tried various recursive functions with no luck.  So I have no clue to what I am doing with this.

Here is the code I am using to create the gridviews and panels.

```
            int x = 1;

            while (sqlReader.Read())
            {
                // Create Panel Header
                Panel PH = new Panel();
                PH.ID = "PH" + Convert.ToString(x);
                PH.CssClass = "cheader";

                // Add Label inside header panel to display text
                Label lblPH = new Label();
                lblPH.ID = "lblPH" + Convert.ToString(x);
                lblPH.Text = sqlReader["Category"].ToString();
                PH.Controls.Add(lblPH);

                //Create Body Panel
                Panel PB = new Panel();
                PB.ID = "PB" + Convert.ToString(x);

                // Create CollapsiblePanelExtender
                CollapsiblePanelExtender CPE = new CollapsiblePanelExtender();
                CPE.ID = "CPE" + Convert.ToString(x);
                CPE.TextLabelID = lblPH.ID;
                CPE.ExpandControlID = PH.ID;
                CPE.CollapseControlID = PH.ID;
                CPE.TargetControlID = PB.ID;
                CPE.ScrollContents = false;
                CPE.Collapsed = true;
                CPE.ExpandDirection = CollapsiblePanelExpandDirection.Vertical;
                CPE.SuppressPostBack = true;

                this.UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(PH);
                this.UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(PB);
                this.UpdatePanel1.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(CPE);

                //*** This is loading the gridview user control

                EPOGVSurvey ctl = Page.LoadControl("EPOGVSurvey.ascx") as EPOGVSurvey;
                ctl.MyParameterValue = sqlReader["Category"].ToString();
                ctl.ID = "CAT" + x;

                PB.Controls.Add(ctl);
                PB.CssClass = "cdata";

                x++;
            }

            sqlReader.Close();
```

Code to try to read the gridviews

```
GridView gv = FindControlRecursive(Page, "Gridview" + i) as GridView;
if (gv != null)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gv.Rows)
    {
```

Comment: The problem with dynamic control is you will need to reload the control with same id on every post back of the page. Please look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16723981/296861) simple example. If you still have question, please post the code about creating and reloading those dynamic controls.

Comment: I am using it as an entry form so I will not have an issue with post back.  I updated the post and added the code I am using to create it

Comment: Your Gridview is within a UserControl (`EPOGVSurvey.ascx`) you need to find the instances of `EPOGVSurvey` then you can access each Griview directly via a public ReadOnly Property

Comment: I believe fnostro is correct -- in your code to read the gridviews, you need to be searching for EPOGVSurvey controls, not GridViews.

Comment: I don't believe that is correct when I view source the gridviews are getting rendered with IDs I was establishing,

Comment: <table class="Grid" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="ContentPlaceHolderBody_CAT1_GV1" style="width:90%;border-collapse:collapse;">